# Is it possible to use "after a long time" or "after a long interval" this way?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd like to know if these two phrases "after a long time" and "after a long interval", which I often find in Japanese-English dictionaries, are used a lot.

I don't want to specify how much time has passed since I did something. So instead of saying

> It's been a long time since I had sushi.
>    or
>   It's been a while since I saw my high school teacher last time.

is it possible to say

> I had sushi after a long time / after a long interval.
>   or
>   I saw my high school teacher after a long time / after a long interval.

I haven't seen these expressions a lot except for Japanese-English dictionaries.   My question is if these phrases are commonly used in the way I wrote above.

Also I have one more question: if I say, "I had sushi for the first time in a long time" does it sound natural?

Comment: You might consider, "I hadn't had sushi for a long time" or "I hadn't seen my high school teacher for a long time."  Both of which imply that after some long period of time, you did finally do each of those things again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not common to use "after a long interval" to mean "after a long time."  Your sentence "I had sushi for the first time in a long time" sounds perfectly natural.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time is used commonly.
I have seen people posting on Facebook and other social sites as "visited my home after long back"  OR  "Enjoying at xyz location after long back" which i think totally illogical and meaningless.